# Disable caching for entire file system or disk?

Tags: filesystems, hard-disk, cache, ssd

I have a 1TB M.2 SSD drive that I use for regularly creating really large tarballs. It just has an ext4 file system on it at the moment. Is there some way I can tell the kernel not to cache data on this file system? I heard about the sync mount option, but apparently that only affects writes. I'd like to disable reads too. Anyone know how?

Comment: [This tool](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pagecache-mangagement/) should help you

Comment: Under which unix variant? Linux?